# UITextView with selected text covered by popover shows selection grab handle in popover

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, selection, popover

I'm working on an app for iPad that includes some text editing in a UITextView.  I have a toolbar over the textview with buttons that can be used to modify the text, such as font, font size, bold, italics, etc. When the user taps the Font button in the toolbar, a popover view controller (not full screen) appears below the button with a list of fonts to choose from.  My problem is that when I select text that starts at the left edge of the textview and then tap the font button in my toolbar, the left selection grab handle appears in my popover.  Worse yet, I can drag the grab handle and change the selection but can't see what the selection is because it's covered by the popover.  Even more odd is that the left selection grab handle has to be before the first character on any line of text in the textview.  If I move the left grab handle to the right one or more characters and tap the Font button, I don't see the grab handle in the popover.

I assumed I was doing something wrong but after days of playing with this I'm beginning to think this is a bug in the SDK.  I was able to reproduce this with a very simple project that includes a button over a textview and a popover view controller, so there's nothing exotic about my code.

Below are some screen shots showing the simple app with selected text and then the same thing but with the Font Selection button tapped.  Note the blue dot in the popover.

Selected Text:

[image: img]

Font Selection button tapped:

[image: img]

Has anyone else experienced this and is there a workaround?  I've been searching but haven't seen this documented elsewhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the example? Have you filed a bug report with Apple?

Comment: This is my first post to Stack Overflow.  What's the best way to post the example code?  I didn't file a bug report with Apple but thought about doing that.  I wasn't sure where to post it in the Apple developer site.

Comment: Can you post it on github? Or even zip it into your Dropbox and provide a link. I’ll submit the report if you like, if you’ve got a clear reproducible case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I put it on GitHub at https://github.com/bbonetti/TextViewProblem/tree/sample-code.  That's my first post to GitHub so let me know if you have any problems and I'll post it elsewhere as a zip file.

Comment: Yup I can reproduce it easily with that.

Comment: Only problem really is that your code is much more complicated than is needed to demonstrate the issue. :) I deleted most of it and I can still get the issue just fine.

Comment: I also can add code so that the selection and the appearance of the popover all happens in code. You just run the app and presto, there's the bug with no action on your part.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I know it's more complicated than it needs to be.  I was able to get it to happen with just a view appearing over the selected text, no popover needed.  If you submit it to Apple, let me know where and how you did that so I can do it myself in the future.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just go to https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/. That will take you to the feedback site. You can submit your report and project there. It will be good experience for you! And thanks for the info about the view. This is a good bug.

Comment: Just facing the same issue here, any luck?